# Data in EXCEL, PDF, WORD (Data will be text, tables, images) to XML

Tags: xml, excel, pdf, ms-word, converters

Is there any free tool to convert data in EXCEL sheets, PDF files and WORD files (Data will be text,tables,images) to XML?

I had searched but mostly getting the opposite thing (Converting from XML to Others)

Please try to provide any tools/links/Code if available.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a "Save As" XML option when I do the Save as in the File tab.  I am not sure if that is part of a XML extensions pack that I have though.  Regardless you can probably get the extensions pack from  Microsoft  if you do not have one.    I also have a Developer tab which probably came from one one of the expansion packs.

Word (and PDF) probably do not have that but you can import any text data into Excel and go from there.  To import data do Data tab -> From Text command.

I have Excel 2010.

Comment: hey i tried "Save As" XML, but i cant use that XML for my application its very detailed and difficult to parse those XML and cant handle images.

Comment: This site indicates how to get an image in there: http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/14/p/113/717.aspx I will look to see if you can reduce the amount of data coming out...

Comment: About half way down  in this:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-xml-in-excel-HA010206396.aspx     there is a section indicating on how you can merge cells which I think would help with your problem.

Comment: @smit shah, if you feel this answer has helped you please "Accept" it by clicking on the downward facing green arrow beneath the "useful" number.  You can also click on the "useful" number if this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

For Word, Google "custom xml data binding".  Excel has a similar concept.